# Клонирование узлов: cloneNode никак не меняется название в клонированном <li> (последние 3 строчки)

Tags: javascript

```js
let navitem = document.createElement('ul');
navitem.className = "navbar-nav";
navitem.setAttribute("id", "nav");
navmenu.prepend(navitem);
navitem.style.margin = "auto";
let navli = document.createElement('li');
navli.className = "nav-item";
navitem.prepend(navli);
let navlink = document.createElement('a');
navlink.className = "nav-link";
navlink.setAttribute("href", "index.html")
navli.prepend(navlink);
navlink.innerHTML = "главная";
let li2 = navli.cloneNode(true);
li2.querySelector('navlink').innerHTML = 'о нас';
navli.after(li2)
```

Comment: `li2.querySelector('navlink')` - тут идет попытка получения элемента с тегом `navlink` -  у тебя действительно есть такой элемент в разметке?

Comment: Выложите Вашу разметку html, чтобы можно было сделать наглядный работающий пример в соответствии с Вашими данными.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, разметка как раз в сниппете и собирается

Comment: @Denis640Kb, в body ничего нету. Всё создано исключительно в menu.js файле